# How can I show time in the label of jQ Range slider?

Tags: javascript, datetime, rangeslider

I have tried to use a plugin JQRangeslider to make a datetime filter, but the label of the filter only showed date, but not time. I checked the documentation, but it didn't tell me how to do.

And this is the documentation of jQRangeSlider

http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `formatter` configuration option to write your format method.

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wuxiandiejia/Lkmbfnqs/)

```
$("#slider").dateRangeSlider({
    formatter: function(v){
    return v.toUTCString();
  },
  bounds: {min: new Date(2012, 0, 1, 10,30,10), max: new Date(2012, 11, 31, 12, 59, 59)},
    defaultValues: {min: new Date(2012, 1, 10), max: new Date(2012, 4, 22)},
    step:{days:2}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I added code like this instead:
`formatter: function(val){
 
var days = val.getDate(),
        month = val.getMonth() + 1,
        year = val.getFullYear(),
        hour = val.getHours(),
        min = val.getMinutes();
        return days + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + hour + ":" + min;
    }`

Comment: @Desmond Lai can you [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer?